# ScITE for Python installation issues

Tags: python, scite

Why I cannot install SciTE for Python? I have downloaded SciTE from the official website.Maybe I have to have an older version of Python?

Comment: You need to specify a platform your operating system. (Windows or Linux?)

Comment: If Linux what Distro you have?

Comment: I have Windows 8 with 64bit. I am not quite following the way/logic of installing this program...Why is so difficult and tricky?

Answer (score 0):

I'm explaining for Debian:

1. You need to download .deb package from the list here: https://packages.debian.org/stable/scite

For amd64(64-bit): http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/scite/scite_3.5.0-1_amd64.deb

For i386(32-bit): http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/scite/scite_3.5.0-1_i386.deb

2. For installation: `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/scite_3.5.0-1_amd64.deb`